# Переключить графический адаптер средствами COM

Tags: c++, windows, com, directx, dxgi

Нужно передать видеоадаптер устройству dx перед его созданием. Получаю список всех видеоадаптеров таким образом:

```
struct VideoAdapters
{
    vector<wstring> NameGPU;
    int index_select;
    VideoAdapters():index_select(-1){}
};

VideoAdapters vAdapt;
do
{
    result = factory->EnumAdapters(i++, &adapter);
    if (FAILED(result))
        break;
    result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc); // получаем информацию о видеокарте по текущему индексу
    if (FAILED(result))
        break;
    vAdapt.NameGPU.push_back(adapterDesc.Description); // помещаем имя видеокарты в вектор
    adapter->Release();
} while (true);
```

Далее вызывается окно, там мы выбираем адаптер, что нам нужен.(обычный диалог с комбо, где мы получаем индекс адаптера)
Теперь самое интересное. Если адаптеров несколько(самый частый случай: интегрированный и дискретный), то текущий адаптер в системе надо переключить, ибо все устройства вывода(мониторы etc) принадлежат текущему видеоадаптеру. Каким образом переключить видеоадаптер на любой другой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если у вас несколько адаптеров (комбинированный адаптер) с внутренней коммутацией вывода (как это бывает на лаптопах), то работающий адаптер может переключаться автоматически, а для его задания програмно придется использовать вендорно-зависимый способ. Например [NVidia Optimus Rendering Policies](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf).
2. Если у вас несколько отдельных адаптеров с отдельными выходами, то переключить адаптер может только пользователь переподключив монитор (вытащив кабель из одно адаптера и воткнув в другой). При этом адаптер без выхода потенциально может использоваться для вспомогательного рендеринга.

Comment: Забыл уточнить: каким способом можно определить, какой адаптер графический, а какой дискретный?